# Taskqueue tasks not executing in dev server

Tags: go, configuration, task-queue

I have enqueued tasks to local taskqueue server using the google task queue library [google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue). But the execution is failing with the following error:

`INFO     2021-05-24 09:28:13,310 module.py:865] default: "POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1" 409 104`
`WARNING  2021-05-24 09:28:13,310 taskqueue_stub.py:2149] Task task36 failed to execute. This task will retry in 204.800 seconds`

Is there some config in dev server that i need to configure for this to work? The same is working on production environment, but only dev server has this problem
I'm using Go version  1.11.13

Comment: 409 (from the 1st error) looks like a HTTP status code, and it is ["Conflict"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409). Does this shed some light to your case? All-in-all, I'd modify that `module.py` to dump the body of the response into the log when the request end with a non-200 HTTP status.

Comment: Also please note that [the language is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang).

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Although, i see that the issue is when i connect to absolute endpoint, whose port number is different from what app is running on... through taskqueues. If i give relative path within the app, it works well